# Why does KeepassXC auto-type prompt me to select entry when I only have one entry?

Tags: keepassxc

I want the password to fill in as soon as I hit the shortcut without popping up KeepassXC for a redundant click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In KeepassXC preferences, Auto-Type tab, turn off "always ask before performing Auto-Type".